# I can't install PyQt5-tools

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyuic

I am trying to install PyQt5-tools but I'm having trouble with it.
I'm getting the error that you can see below:

```
Collecting pyqt5-tools
Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.4
Using cached PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [29 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

```
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\bugra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lqdj0vd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
      project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
    File "C:\Users\bugra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lqdj0vd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
      project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
    File "C:\Users\bugra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lqdj0vd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 584, in setup
      self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\bugra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9mv2p235\pyqt5_e5532f6d13a1499ab609510184a6e714\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\bugra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lqdj0vd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\bugra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lqdj0vd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 236, in apply_user_defaults
      self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\bugra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lqdj0vd3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
      raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
  sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: Last time I checked, pyqt5-tools were not available for Python>=3.10. Try to downgrade to 3.9

Comment: You might also try the [work-around given here](https://github.com/altendky/pyqt-tools/issues/98#issuecomment-968296553).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I researched, I saw that if you are using 3.10 version in python, pyqt5-tools cannot be installed in this version, I recommend you to install 3.9 version[image]